# Kotlin Retrofit Query Annotation parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

So I have have this an interface for the `NetworkConfig.kt` class:

```
interface getProductList {
    @GET("stock")
    fun getProducts(@Query("outcode") stkOutcode: String): Call<OutletListPOJODataClasses>
}
```

and this is a code snippet from the *Activity* I use to fetch url:

```
NetworkConfig().getProductListService()
        .getProducts() //What should i pass here ?
        .enqueue(object : Callback<ProductListPOJODataClasses> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProductListPOJODataClasses>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), t.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<ProductListPOJODataClasses>,
                response: Response<ProductListPOJODataClasses>
            ) {
                binding.rvProductList.adapter = response.body()?.let { ProductListAdapter(it, this@ProductListFragment) }

                Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), "Data retrieved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
```

And this is the data class I use:

```
data class ProductListPOJODataClassesDataItem(

    @field:SerializedName("stk_prodcode")
    val stkProdcode: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("stk_allqty")
    val stkAllqty: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("pro_saleprice")
    val proSaleprice: Int? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("skt_lastupdate")
    val sktLastupdate: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("stk_outcode")
    val stkOutcode: String? = null,

    @field:SerializedName("pro_name")
    val proName: String? = null
)
```

I'm quite new in using this library. What I want to know is what should I pass in the `.getProducts()` function above? If there's anything unclear, let me know.

Comment: you should pass the value of `outcode` in the url.  example: `https://example.com/api/stock?outcode=value_here` You're supposed to pass the query parameter for `outcode`. See the [documentation](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/Query.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
NetworkConfig().getProductListService()
    .getProducts(stkOutcode = stkOutcodeValue)
    ....
```

where `stkOutcodeValue` (*String* type) should be known or a default value might be used, if applicable.

Thanks to @sonnet, the endpoint in this case is `https://example.com/api/stock?outcode=stkOutcodeValue`